# How to manage single cron job for mutliple time zone

Tags: cron, node-cron

I want to create single cron job for UTC time and send notification to users according to their timezone time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow the below steps to send notifications to user's timezone.

1. Create a Cronjob (Set the interval according to your requirement)
2. Now fetch all users records.
3. Get every user's timezone.
4. Now, convert your datetime to user's timezone.
5. Match your current time to user's timezone time
6. If the time matches according to the user's timezone, then send notification to that user only.

**Updated,** for example a user has timezone GMT +530 and you server has timezone GMT 0 then if you get the user's record whose notification time is 4:30 PM and at the same time your server time would be 11:00 AM. Now the cronjob runs at 11:00 AM, according to that user timezone you need to add 5:30 hours in your current time so 11:00 AM + 5:30 = 4:30 PM(be careful with the date too) which is your user's time, and in that case you can send notification to him.

And if you don't want to set cron for each minute then you can set marginal minutes for checking. Suppose your cron runs in every 10 minutes then you have to check the condition like `converted_time >= 4:20 and converted_time < 4:30`. (Remember the `>=` and `<` combination here)

Comment: ok but how can we know the exact time of users timezone like 9:30, i don't want to run cronjob every min